# Jquery increase counter

Tags: jquery

```
$('#fCount' + folderID).html(parseInt($('#fCount' + folderID).html()) + "E");
```

That works, but whatever I try such as:

```
$('#fCount' + folderID).html(parseInt($('#fCount' + folderID).html())++);
```

Doesn't work!  The html is just a number, like 0 or 8.  I just want to increment it by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
$('#fCount' + folderID).html(parseInt($('#fCount' + folderID).html())+1);
```

The `++` operator won't work in this case. It can only be used for variables. You need to do `+1`.

Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UVR4t/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply add one (`+1`) rather than incrementing, which only works on a variable.

You could also use this rather nicer jQuery syntax:

```
$('#fCount' + folderID).html(function(i, oldHtml) {
    return parseInt(oldHtml, 10) + 1; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the `++` operator only works on variables that you maintain a reference to. In this case you don't have a reference to a value, you have an actual value being returned. You'll either need to store the value in a variable, and then increment the number, or add one manually:

```
something = parseInt(someString)+1
```